# Simpel image toggle function won't work (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make this simpel image toggle on click function work but I am not sure what is wrong. I have to use querySelector and addEventListener, also jquery is not allowed. Could anyone please help me figure this out?

```
document.querySelector(".imageClass").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var img = this.src;
    if(img.src == "/image/location1.png") {
        img.src = "/image/location2.png";
    } else {
        img.src = "/image/location2.png";
    }
});
```

I'm getting this error:

```
document.querySelector(...).addEventlistener is not a function(...)
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. What errors are you getting?

Comment: document.querySelector(...).addEventlistener is not a function(...)

Comment: @adeneo  What should be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a property would most likely return an absolute URL, and you really want to make sure you check the attribute, not the property.

Also, you're accesing `src` twice, first by doing `var img = this.src` then by doing `img.src`

And your condition does the same thing in both cases

```
document.querySelector(".imageClass").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var img = this;
    var src = img.getAttribute('src');

    if( src == "/image/location1.png" ) {
        img.src = "/image/location2.png";
    } else {
        img.src = "/image/location1.png";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Recieve your event by passing it with your parameters. From there you can access the target element of the event and get its `src` attribute.

```
document.querySelector(".imageClass").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  var img = e.target;
  if(img.src == "/image/location1.png") {
    img.src = "/image/location2.png";
  } else {
    img.src = "/image/location2.png";
  }
});
```